# Linking to an action from a non-React environment

Tags: reactjs, react-native, hyperlink, react-router

My frontend is WordPress @ https://www.rein.com.  The backend is powered by a vendor and integrated via reserve proxy.  (e.g. https://rein.com/search equals https://reinmls.enclosuresites.com/search).

On WordPress (frontend) I need to add a "Login" link to the back end.

```
<a class="Toolbar_label"><!-- react-text: 141 -->Sign in or register<!-- /react-text --></a>
```

The login function is handled by React and I can't identify how I can link directly to it from the front end.  Is this possible?  If not, what workarounds are available to consider?  Could I add ?example to the login URL and when the users lands on https://rein.com/search?example could Tag Manager perform a function to load the link?  Or?

Another thought.  I could link the login URL with a UTM code then use tag manager to deploy "something" to trigger the react login link based on a specific url.

Thank you!